# Проблема с кэшированием медиа из-за поддоменов | Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Обнаружил проблему с кэшем, но пока не могу понять, как её поправить. У меня есть 2 источника медия (папка /public, и отдельный поддомен files.site.com). Когда в событии 'fetch' я делаю fetch(e.request), то в ответ мне выдает:

```
[public] -> Response {type: 'basic', url: ...}
[files.site.com] -> Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', ...}
```

И получается так, что первый вариант у меня закэшировать получается, а вот второй выдает response.ok === false. Есть ли какой-то способ закэшировать такие медиа?

Comment: Какое кеширование? Зачем нужно делать fetch?

Comment: `self.addEventListener('fetch', async (e) => { 
   const remote = await fetch(e.request);
   if (remote.ok) {
      //save to cache
   }
   e.respondWith(remote) 
})` на подобии вот этого

Comment: Ну, остаётся только вдумчиво читать про CORS (в частности про opaque https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque) и задуматься зачем вообще всё это городить, а не пользоваться браузерным кешированием…